# Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'Id' at line 8 column 31

Tags: trigger

```
trigger accountTestTrggr1 on Account(before insert, before update) {
    for (Account a: Trigger.new) {

        List < Contact > contacts = [select id, salutation, firstname, lastname, email
        from Contact where accountId = : a.Id];

        for (Contact c: contacts) {
            System.debug(Contact Id[' + c.Id + '], FirstName[' + c.firstname + '],
            LastName[' + c.lastname +']);
            c.Description = c.salutation + ' ' + c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastname;

            update c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is from the system.debug statement. you have to correct the format of the parameters you are trying to debug.. properly concatenate them and it should work

Answer (score 2):

Your `System.debug` statement should look like this:

```
System.debug('Contact Id[' + c.Id + '], FirstName[' + c.firstname + '], LastName[' + c.lastname +']');
```

(You were missing a `'` character). Also, you can't break lines in Apex - you need to concatenate a string to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature of debug method.you had missed the ' character ,which is the required part for that method.

debug(logLevel, msg)
Writes the specified message, in string format, to the execution debug log with the specified log level.
Signature

```
public static Void debug(LoggingLevel logLevel, Object msg)

System.debug('Contact Id[' + c.Id + '], FirstName[' + c.firstname + '], LastName[' + c.lastname +']');
```